# How to Protect Server Connection Authentication in Code

Tags: c#, security, authentication, password-protection

In many Application's i had Cases where i should write Username and Password's in my Application inside the Class ,like HTTP Authentication ,FTP Authentication MSSQL Server Connection String also Provides Authentication Information's ,so which is the Best way to protect these Information's because someone could Decompile my Application easily maybe using Reflector and get these Information's which can be useful for some Attack's or something like that .

Bests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you explain more specifically what your general goal is? Usually there's better designs than hard coding passwords and authentication tokens.

There's really nothing you can do to protect those secrets if you are distributing your application. Even encrypting your config files, the application still needs the key to decrypt, so your attacker has all they need.

You can choose other designs though, such as prompting a user for their own unique password, and then making database calls against a web service, rather than distributing an application that connects directly to a central database. But you'd have to explain the scenario for a better recommendation.

Comment: I had a case where a software should get Connected with an FTP Server and list all of it's files (XML Files in general) ,so there shouldn't be more than a Username and Password cuz all Client's should List these Files no matter else ,so in that situation prompting user to Type Password where a Critical Issue ,so in that case i should kept the password in the Code.

Comment: The problem you'll have is that if you hard code the FTP password, there's really nothing you can do to protect it. Is this application being distributed to a lot of people? Is it an internal app? Is it possible to prompt the user for a password to decrypt these sensitive strings? If you can't prompt the user and you can't proxy things through an external resource, trying to secure store the password is a chicken and egg problem

Comment: So just in case which is the best way to Proxy these ,using SOAP by sending XML Messages or a Web Service by sending to a Web Service Application Checksum and the Web Service Reply with Authentication stuff ?